# Observer pattern, how to link it with order queue in class diagram?

Tags: class, design-patterns, uml, observer-pattern, class-diagram

So I am working on this class diagram, I do get the idea that we need to implement observer pattern with order and customer class, however I couldn't understand what is the best possible way to maintain a relation between order queue ,staff and orders.

Original Question

A simple web application that allows customer to place orders select one or multiple items. As soon as the customer proceeds and confirms the order, The order get enlisted in the order Queue. Customer gets a confirmation for the order that he/she has place and mean while staff also gets notified for the new order via GUI of system.

[The Class Diagram that I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxRyN.jpg)

Comment: This is not a homework service. Ask a question.

Comment: How do I maintain Order Queue for such system ? Should I have it with a system class that association with Orders ? Or there should be a link between staff and Order Queue as well ?

Comment: Please simplify your original question.

Comment: Please see if it is understandable now ?

Comment: Still, what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You have different observers i-e Customer and Staff member. So you will be having Staff and Customer as subclass of Observer.

Subject is Order. Whenever an order is placed/updated, you go through list of observers and notify them. So your diagram is correct where Order is subclass of Subject.

The orderItem can be of different type. You should inherit different subclasses from parent "Item" class.(You are currently inheriting items from Gift Item".

There should be an aggregation relationship between "Item" and subject.